# Payload is not passed to the handler

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a small example web application. I would like to send the id from a table to the appropriate post handler with an Ajax call. I get to the handler but somehow the payload gets lost along the way. The developer tools (network) correctly output the ID in the payload section. However, only a 0 arrives in the post handler.

In addition, I would also find it interesting how I could pass an entire object to the Ajax function.

Thanks in advance for the help.

**View**

```html
foreach (var student in Model.Students)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@student.StudentId</td>
        <td>@student.Salutation</td>
        <td>@student.FirstName</td>
        <td>@student.LastName</td>
        <td>@student.EmailAddress</td>
        <td>@student.City</td>
        <td>@student.CreatedOn.ToString("ddd., dd.MM.yyyy")</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="DeleteStudentRecord(@student.StudentId)">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Ajax script**

```js
function DeleteStudentRecord (studentId) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("DeleteStudentRecord", "Students")',
      data: {StudentId: studentId},
      dataType: "json"
   });
}
```

**Post handler** (*StudentsController.cs*)

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteStudentRecord(int id)
{
    StudentViewModel viewModel = new();

    _studentService.DeleteStudent(id);

    viewModel.Students = _studentService.GetAllStudents();
    ModelState.Clear();

    return View("StudentsList", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the id in the body or URL? `{StudentId: studentId}` can not be converted to `integer` value because `id` id not mapped to any body parameter. If you need to receive `id` in the JSON body then you should create a class with `public int StudentId {get;set;}` property and use it as parameter in action method.

Comment: Hello Chetan,
Thank you for your quick help. I want to submit the payload in the Json body. I don't quite understand how I can use a property as a parameter in a handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax script must be like :

```
    function DeleteStudentRecord (studentId) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '@Url.Action("DeleteStudentRecord", "Students")',
      data: {id: studentId},
      dataType: "json"
   });
}
```

Because in your Students controller DeleteStudentRecord action wait for id and not for StudentId.

or you can change id to StudentId in your DeleteStudentRecord action.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. That was the solution.

Comment: @Tauwin If you approve the answer, people can see that the question has been answered. thanks.